# What does the symbol with a squiggly line mean?

Tags: notation

[image]

What does the symbol above mean?

Answer (score 7):

It's a *[glissando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissando)*.

I can be notated a few ways.

[image]

Execution depends on the instruments. A trombone can do it continuously with the slide. Keyboard, fretted, etc. instruments will have discrete pitches.

The wavy line can also indicate an *arpeggio* on chords...

[image]

...where you sweep quickly through only the tones of the chord.

Watch out for the different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

It means slide up through two octaves from the low C to the high C. On piano, you'd most likely run a finger over the white keys, ending on top C.